# Undoing change of ownership to var directory

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, permissions, chown

I accidently ran `sudo chown -R user:user *.*` (on Ubuntu 11.1) inside `/var` directory..

Even after running `sudo chown -R root:root *.*` (and rebooting) I keep getting GUI messages that some operations are not allowed (permission errors) and even trying to run mysql, raises

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Can this be undone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're going to have a headache fixing that manually. Your best bet is to restore from backup.

Answer (score 0):

Not easily.  /var isn't owned entirely by root.  Individual bits of software own individual directories there.  For example, /var/run/mysqld should be owned by the MySQL user.  Your best bet is to fix these permissions as you encounter errors.

Comment: Don't forget the old `/var/spool/mail`, either. ☺

Comment: Also make sure that the ownership of `/var/lib/mysql/` is set to `mysql:mysql`.